# NSPasteboard Event for data access

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I want to offer drag and drop functionality in my mac app.

For example I have file that is encrypted. I have a question in regarding when the user drag and file out of my app into let's say finder. I want to provide the other app the decrypted file. Are there events for NSPasteboard that let's me know when the drag is finished to the other app and the app is ready to access the data?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no notifications or events and there's nothing to observe for changed pasteboard contents.

You can try to set up NSDragOperationPrivate operation flag if you want more security during drag operation. Check Apple's "[Drag and Drop Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Concepts/dragsource.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000976-104936)".